# Shell script to scan logs to get exceptions in one go from different servers

Tags: python, shell

I've got a task to prepare a script to scan logs from different Unix Server (for same application). The requirement is that preparation of shell script where I'll pass the string as inputs which needs to be grep in different log locations (diff server).

So, script should read servers from one file and stores the results in a specific location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [`multitail`](http://www.codekoala.com/posts/monitor-multiple-remote-files-using-multitail/) which is able to help you there

```
multitail -l 'ssh user@host1 "tail -f /path/to/log/file"' -l 'ssh user@host2 "tail -f /path/to/log/file"'
```

to gather logs from different servers.

*EDIT:*

1. Running continuously:

If you want to search for certain lines on every log files you gather remotely, this would look like this:

```
multitail -E "search-string" --mergeall -l 'ssh user@host1 "tail -f /path/to/log/file"' -l 'ssh user@host2 "tail -f /path/to/log/file"'
```

This will run continuously (tailf on every box) and only show you lines containing "search-string". You will need to have password-less login on the boxes (See [this](http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html)).

2. Running once on whole log files

There'd be plenty of ways to do this including bash, but I like the pythonic way most. In case you want to do it in python, try this. Note, that this also implies a passwordless login at the hosts for the given user:

```
import subprocess
import re

files = [
    ['user@host1', '/path/to/logfile'],
    ['user@host2', '/path/to/logfile'],
]


def get_lines(search_key):
    for item in enumerate(files):
        server = item[1][0]
        logfile = item[1][1]
        ssh = subprocess.Popen(['ssh', server, 'cat', logfile],
                               stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        for line in iter(ssh.stdout.readlines()):
            line=str(line, encoding='UTF-8')
            if re.search(search_key, line):
                print(line)


def main():
    get_lines("needle")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: then how can i take these arguments (user#,password) from a text file containing columns for (servers , user , password)

Comment: @Mr.Tarun I've edited and added some more details.